# Почему блок с текстом не слева?

Tags: html, css

Начал потихоньку разбираться в верстке HTML. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Правил чей-то шаблон. Там есть такие строки:

```
<div id="container_ll">
Container Left.
</div>  

<div id="container_m">
Content.
</div>
```

А в css следующее:

```
/*html Reset*/
*{margin:0;padding:0}
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0}
fieldset,img{border:0}
ul{list-style:circle;list-style-position:inside}
a:focus{outline:none}
html{height:100%;margin-bottom:1px}
/* links */
a:link,a:visited{text-decoration:none}
a:hover{text-decoration:underline}
/* headings */
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-weight:bold;line-height:100%}
h1{font-size:300%}
h2{font-size:250%}
h3{font-size:200%}
h4{font-size:175%}
h5{font-size:150%}
h6{font-size:125%}
/*End of html Reset*/
body{font:12px/150% Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#646464;background:#f2f2f2 url(../images/bkg_body.gif) 0 0 repeat;}
a:link,a:visited{color:#aa1428}
a:hover{color:#f00}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif}
h1{font-weight:normal;color:#7887A0}
h2{color:#b4b4be}
h3{color:#646478}
h4{font-weight:normal;color:#7887A0}
h5{color:#878796}
h6{color:#7887A0}
.inside{padding:0 20px}
.clear{clear:both}

#header{color:#fff;width:100%;height:50px;padding:10px 10px}

a#logo{float:left;width:347px;height:100px;background:url(../images/logo.gif) no-repeat 0 0;padding: 5px;}

#container{margin:auto;background:#f2f2f2 url(../images/bkg_body.gif) 0 0 repeat;width: 960px;height:auto;float: center;}

#container_qa{background:#444;padding: 5px;}

#container_m{background:#ffffff;padding:1px 10px;margin-top:5px;border-right:1px solid #ccc; float: right;width: 60%;}
#container_l{background:#ffffff;padding:1px 10px;margin-top:5px;border-left:1px solid #ccc; float: left;width: 40%;}
```

При этом выглядит все так:
[image: снимок]

Почему блок с текстом Container Left не получается слева? Что не так?

**Добавлено.**

Вот в принципе все, что внутри body на данный момент:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <a id="logo" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>"></a>
        Header.
    </div>

    <div id="container_qa">
    <p>Quick Access</p>
    </div>

    <div id="container_l">
    Container Left.
    </div>    

    <div id="container_m">
    Content.
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: а что идет перед div id="container_ll" в шаблоне?

Comment: Выложите и CSS всю, иначе непонятно, что у вас привязано к container_qa.

Comment: Если вы про #container_m и #container_l, то просто добавить им параметр height=Npx, где N - неоходимая высота в пикселях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем ваше решение:

a). a#logo у вас находится внутри #header, но у #header высота 50px, а у a#logo - 100px, это неправильно. Уберите высоту у a#logo.

б). Добавьте в css такую строчку:

```
.cleared{float: none; clear: both; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; font-size: 1px;}
```

в). вставьте после

```
<div id="header">
        <a id="logo" href="#"></a>
        Header.
    </div>
```

еще один див

```
<div class="cleared"></div>
```

г). установите в #container_m значение width в размере 55%, а не 60

Answer (score 1):

Первая проблема - логотип.

```
<a id="logo" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>"></a>
```

После него стоит разместить:

```
<br style='clear: both' />
```

Или какими-то другими методами отделить его от основного контента.

Comment: Переопределение в css? Там ничего после container_ll нет.

Comment: Выложите, пожалуйста, полностью весь файл. Сдается мне, он не слишком большой.
Весь от и до.

Comment: Поправил.

Answer (score 1):

После

```
< div id="container_qa"/>
    < p>Quick Access</p>
< /div>
```

поставьте

```
< div style='clear:both;height:0px' /> < /div>
```